# Error with iAd implementation means no revenue generated from ads?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iad

For a while now I have had an app on the app store. I decided to try to add support for the Apple iAd Network in a recent update. It has been live for over a month now (at first I thought time would fix it) but I have come to the realisation that the app is still not making any money off of the ad revenue. Currently all my apps are free to download but I need to allow ads to keep them that way.

I am testing ads using this app because it is not my most popular app but if I can get them to work then I will look to update my other apps to support iAds in the future as well.

I cannot see if my live app is making ad requests because I get this error in the iAd Network part of iTunes Connect:

[image: iTunes Connect Error]

The status of this app is Ready for Sale. Below is a screenshot of my app to demonstrate that the iAd banner has been implemented correctly in Xcode to the best of my knowledge.

[image: App Screenshot]

So my question is why is iAd not making me any money from ad revenue as I would expect it to? Have I done something wrong or is the problem with Apple?

### UPDATE

I have now made and published another app with iAds successfully implemented but I still have no ads on this one!

**Could it be due to a lack of popularity?**

Comment: It sounds as if you should follow the advice from the error message and contact them.

Comment: I have through iTunes Connect but I am still waiting on a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

The reason was simply that Apple has delays in processing at their end. I still don't know why one of my apps took so much longer than the other, however it was just a matter of time until the revenue started showing up as I had implemented everything correctly in Xcode.

### Advise

Make sure you follow the official Apple guidelines, make sure to use the proper iAd banner and show it all the time (it will hide automatically when it needs to). Don't forget to setup all your information properly on iTunes connect either, although Apple makes it quite clear in their documentation what needs to be done there.

***Be patient!*** Apple takes time to process these things.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the issues you are facing could be occurring since you haven't setup the contracts for iAds in itunes connect. Also, this may be unrelated, but when no ad loads, is the banner view visible?

Comment: I have setup the iAd contract in iTunes connect with banking details, tax approval and all that. I thought I should keep the banner hidden when there is no ad loaded so as to improve the user experience? Or is this the cause of my issue?

Comment: It seems like all is good. You are required to make the banners hidden if there is no ad loaded. As long as they become unhidden, it should work. Maybe a problem with the iAd servers.